# A partial derivative problem related with elasticity of substitution in Advanced Micro

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, applications

[Exe 3.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjxYc.png) Sorry, it is a problem that appears in Jehle and Reny Advanced Microeconomic Theory (3rd ed) exercise 3.8. But I think it's a partial derivative question.

Letting $f_i(\mathbf{x})=\partial f(\mathbf{x})/\partial x_i$, ($\mathbf{x}$ is a vector, a commodity bundle, and $x_i$ is a scalar, commodity $i$ in the bundle).

Show that (this is my main question.),

$\sigma_{ij}(\mathbf{x})\equiv -\frac{x_if_i(\mathbf{x})+x_jf_j(\mathbf{x})}{f^2_j(\mathbf{x})f_{ii}(\mathbf{x})+2f_i(\mathbf{x})f_j(\mathbf{x})f_{ij}(\mathbf{x})+f_i^2(\mathbf{x})f_{jj}(\mathbf{x})}\frac{f_i(\mathbf{x})f_j(\mathbf{x})}{x_ix_j}$

Then using the above formula, show that $\sigma_{ij}(\mathbf{x})\geq0$ whenever $f$ is increasing and concave.

---

PS: I know $\sigma_{ij}$ can be written as

$\sigma_{ij}=-\frac{d (x_i/x_j)}{x_i/x_j} \frac{f_i(\mathbf{x})/f_j(\mathbf{x})}{d (f_i(\mathbf{x})/f_j(\mathbf{x}))}$

How can we derive the result from this known fact? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it assumed that $x_i \geq 0$ for each $i$? I think we'd have to or else we'd be in trouble. For now I'm assuming $x_i \geq 0$, so that makes $x_ix_j$ positive.

Since $f$ is increasing $f_i(\boldsymbol{x}) \geq 0$ for each $i$. That makes $x_if_i(\boldsymbol{x})+x_jf_j(\boldsymbol{x})$ positive. Finally, $f$ being concave means NEGATIVE second order (partial) derivatives, so
\begin{align*}
f^2_j(\boldsymbol{x})f_{ii}(\boldsymbol{x})+2f_i(\boldsymbol{x})f_j(\boldsymbol{x})f_{ij}(\boldsymbol{x})+f^2_i(\boldsymbol{x})f_{jj}(\boldsymbol{x}),
\end{align*}
is NEGATIVE. That gives us
\begin{align*}
-\frac{+}{-}\frac{+}{+}=+.
\end{align*}
Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. But the problem has two claims. The first is my main question. How to derive the cumbersome mixed derivatives, via a shorter known formula? Yes, x_i >0.

Comment: My bad. I missed that. Will answer your next question soon.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

I emailed the question to one of the authors. He said the solution manual will come soon.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/677124)

Comment: Hi, these two snapshots come from the preprint of the solution manual that an author emailed me. And my question especially in "PS:...$\sigma_{ij}$...this known fact" is equivalent to "S: First note that: $\sigma_{ij}\equiv$...$MRTS_{ij}$..." in the first snapshot. As such, these do answer the question, I think.

Comment: I didn't see the images (?) when doing the review, and thus it looked like a comment. Now that I see the images, I agree that they provide a satisfactory answer.